# How do I start an interactive c shell via ssh with one command/alias/script

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal

I need to use the c shell (tcsh) on a remote box.

At the moment I'm ssh ing in

```
$ ssh remote
```

and then starting the shell

```
jla@remote$ tcsh
```

(then I get a new prompt, and can use it interactively)
How do I do that with a single command (or from a script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssh -t remote tcsh
```

Comment: Indeed it does. Now I feel a complete moron. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- change the shell on the remote box using `chsh` (man chsh for more info), or
- add `exec tcsh` to your `.profile` or whatever is run on this machine after you login, to start the shell immediately

**BUT** be warned, with these things it is really easy to lock yourself out...